# Dropdown selection hangs when we do change a dropdowns options in

Tags: javascript, html, performance, internet-explorer-11, dom-events

Dropdown selection hangs when we do change a dropdowns options in IE11 browser.

However this works in other browsers. How to fix this, why this issue in IE11?

Please click on the button below to see this issue!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
            <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
    x[1]=new Option;
    x[1].text=x[0].text;
    x[1].value=x[0].value;
    x[0].text='sdf';
    x[0].value='sdf';
       }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me in latest IE11 on Win 7. Please specify your operating system and version on IE11

Comment: am using IE11 , 11.0.27 update version in win 7 home version.

Comment: OK - interesting - IE is the same, I have Win 7 Home Premium - is that different from yours? Even if so, I don't see it should affect IE.

What I did is to copy your html above to a temp file and run it in IE11 - worked OK - is there anything else about the environment you are running this html in that may be different from mine?

Comment: please find attached IE details...I too wondering why this strange thing?

Comment: Looks like Iqbal has the real answer - I simply noted that IE didn't hang for me- I didn't question the fact that you ended up with 2 bananas (I just thought - odd??).

(My IE11 is 11.0.27, so a bit older than yours)

Answer (score 0):

in your script code you are changing value and text of the list you have passed array values as given below.

```
x[3].text=x[2].text
x[3].value=x[2].value
```

here you are taking text x[3] array and setting it in x[2] and similarly you are taking the value of x[3] and assigning to x[2] value. as per the IE11 it is changing value as well as text but in other browser it only changing value not text. it should be like below code to set value.

```
x[3].text=x[3].text
x[3].value=x[3].value
```

Comment: ok then how you interchange between x[3] and x[2]....like if if i want interchange between two options, how will i achieve it?

Comment: in the same way example. if you want to change text of x[2] to x[3] and value of x[2] to x[3] => x[2].text=x[3].text;
x[2].value=x[3].value; x[3].text=x[2].text
x[3].value=x[2].value

Comment: you can also use this.val() of clicked list and store in which ever list x[0]...x[3].

Comment: so did u make the above issue to get work in IE11, then pls share code..let me give a try...

Comment: try this 
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
    x[3].value=x[3].value
    x[2].value=x[2].value
    x[3].text=x[2].text
    x[2].text=x[3].value
    x[3].text=x[2].value
}